# Is it possible to name an organization as the executor of my "last will"?

Tags: california, wills

Is it possible to name an organization as the executor of my "last will"? I don't have any children. My will is just going to be a formality, since I'm only 41, so I'd rather not spend a ton on legal counsel. According to some things I read online (which I can't necessarily trust), this kind of law is determined by each state, but I'm not sure how to find specific and accurate details about the law in any particular state. At the moment I'm a resident of California, though I'm finishing grad school and may move elsewhere soon. The sole beneficiary of my will is going to be a charitable organization, so it seems prudent to name the organization as executor of the will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [California Probate Code Section 6240-6243](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=prob&group=06001-07000&file=6240-6243):

> 14. What is an executor?  An "executor" is the person you name to
>       collect your assets, pay your debts and taxes, and distribute your
>       assets as the court directs. It may be a person or it may be a
>       qualified bank or trust company.